# Stacktraces after proguard have wrong line numbers in Kotlin files

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I use AppCenter to log crashes for my apps.
AppCenter automatically builds the apps for the store, and manages the mapping files.

I see in the crash logs in AppCenter, that the stacktraces in Kotlin files show the wrong line numbers, like the mapping file is not used.
For example it says the crash happened at line 1261, but the source file only has 294 lines. This is the case for all kotlin files.

But the crashes that happen in java files, are all correct.

I also uploaded the mapping files to the Play Console, and the logs are identical to AppCenter. So this leads me to believe it is an issue with the mapping files being wrong for kotlin files.

How would I be able to fix the mappings for the kotlin files? I can't seem to find anything specific why kotlin files would be wrong, but java files are correct.